# Real time lookups from Oracle database in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have requirement where we are loading data from Kinesis to Oracle using spark streaming in real time and sometimes we need to do lookkup if we are getting event for say table A we need to lookup table B in oracle .

How do we achieve this ? using spark its slow to load table from Oracle.

Tried loading entire table in spark and its slow as it needs to load the table every micro batch